# Adding child nodes(Hyperlinks) to a ES6/JSX webpage div(Navigation Bar)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use reactjs/jsx/es6(I'm not sure which one is the right term to use) to create a website that is just a navigation bar with 3 links on it. This is a plain html file that would do the same thing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navBar.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="navBar">
      <a link='#About' class="navBarItem">About</a>
      <a link='#Publications' class="navBarItem">Publications</a>
      <a link='#Contact' class="navBarItem">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my html file which includes reactjs and ES6 script embedded. The navigation bar is printed to the screen, but I cannot see any of the links.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.2/browser.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navBar.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="navBar"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

        NavBar = () => {
            return (
                <div id="navBar">
                    <NavBarItem link='#About' text='About'/>
                    <NavBarItem link='#Publications' text='Publications'/>
                    <NavBarItem link='#Contact' text='Contact'/>
                </div>
            )
        }

        NavBarItem = () => {
            return (
                <a href={this.props.link} class="navBarItem">{this.props.text}</a>
            )
        }

        ReactDOM.render(
            <NavBar />,
            document.getElementById('navBar')
        )
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

---

**navBar.css**

```
.navBarItem {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 31%;
    background: #016241;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    transition: background 1s;
    height: 49px;
    line-height: 49px;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#navBar {
    background: #016241;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 49px;
    column-count: 3;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const NavBar = (props) => {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <NavBarItem link='#About' text='About'/>
                <NavBarItem link='#Publications' text='Publications'/>
                <NavBarItem link='#Contact' text='Contact'/>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

const NavBarItem = (props) => {
        return (
            <a href={props.link} className="navBarItem">{props.text}</a>
        )
    }
```

1 - "NavBarItem" and "NavBar" are functional components so You can not use the keyword “this”. Since they're not a class you don’t have to reference the component itself.

2 - in react you have to use "classname" to set css class name

Comment: It looks like I also need a word like const or var in front of navBar or navBarItem, you included it in your code, but didn't bring it up. Is that just a javascript thing?

Comment: Because of the readability and efficiency of the code, the values ​​of the code that do not change define as const way.